# Python check if value exists in dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've got a Python dictionary, as follows:

```
users = {'user': {'pw': 'password'}}
```

How do I check if the value exist in the dictionary?

I would receive a false in the following if statement:

```
if 'password' in users:
        return 'true'
else:
        return 'false'
```

Comment: You should organize your data in such a way that the operations you want to perform are cheap, and finding out whether a dictionary contains a value is already expensive, let alone a nested value. Also, there is pretty much never a reason to check whether a password is in use. It just leaks information and makes it easy to break into your system.

Comment: @user2357112 My intuition is that the OP won't understand what you have just said.

Comment: @nbro: Mine too, but exposure to the information may be useful for future understanding, even if he doesn't understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

You have a dictionary within a dictionary, so to check if any user (top level) has password (key 'pw') set to 'password', you can use:

```
return 'password' in (user['pw'] for user in users.itervalues())
```

Also note that the boolean values in Python are `True` and `False`. If you wanted to return strings `'true'` and `'false'`, you can do:

```
return 'true' if 'password' in (user['pw'] for user in users.itervalues()) else 'false'
```

Answer (score -1):

You would do

```
if users['user']['pw'] == 'password':
    return 'true'
else:
    return 'false'
```